# Loop items into different divs

Tags: php, random, html

I have ten spans in my css, all with different widths: span1, span2, span3..., span10.

I'd like to loop an array of posts and display every posts in randomized span names...

How could I achieve something like this without hardcoding spans in the html and using multiple queries?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$posts=array('a','b','c');

$rand=range(1,10);
shuffle($rand);
$count=current($rand);
foreach($posts as $p){
    echo '<span style="css'.$rand[$count].'">'.$p.'</span>';
    $count=next($rand);
}
```